# NAT'ing on Oracle Virtual Box doesnt works with static host-only IPs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I am facing the below problem on Oracle Virtual Box. Posting it here
in case anyone has faced the similar issue.

I have a 2 node Juno setup on Oracle VBox.
I have configured one of my interfaces as NAT (For internet access,
package downloads etc)
The other interfaces are configured as Host-Only so that I can SSH
into the VM from my Windows machine.

I have assigned static IPs (192.168.56.*) to these host only
interfaces due to OpenStack configuration.

Observation:
When I give a static IP , the NAT interfaces doesn;t gets IP. When i
run dhclient for the NAT interface, it gets 10.0.2.15 as its IP. Even
after that internet doesn't works.
I have edited nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf, even then it doesnt works.

So the question is:
In a VM having 2 interfaces(NAT and host-only), if we give a static IP
to host only interface (192.168.56 series), the internet access doesnt
works on the NAT interface.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after commenting gateway IP in /etc/network/interfaces.

 Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446183/how-to-set-up-nat-and-host-only-networking-with-static-ip-address-in-virtualbox 
auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.56.104

netmask 255.255.255.0

 #gateway 192.168.56.1

Thanks